# LoadRunner - Generating a 8 digit Random Number

Tags: loadrunner

I'm trying to Load Test web application with Customer Registration where customer is passing 36 digits unique bill number to complete the registration and i've tried below code but not working and found from internet.

```
lr_save_string("RandNum",lr_eval_string("{rNum}"));
    RandNum = lr_eval_string("{rNum}");  
    //rNum is an LR param of type random (4 digit)
    lr_output_message("Random number string is %s", RandNum);
```

Please anyone provide proper code in loadrunner to generate unique 8 digits for each iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James Pulley mentioned, you can create a parameter.[image: create a random number parameter]

And then use it in the code (my script is in JavaScript but you can use equivalent API in C)
[image: use the parameter]

Comment: Hi Buzzy,Thank you for your reply ,above images are not opening displaying Not Found,Can you please provide the code.

Comment: There is no code, just define a parameter with parameter type "Random Number"

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not use the built in parameter item for random number?

Comment: It's called product training